# Azure Cognitive Search Hit Highlighting full phrase

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, hit-highlighting

This is a question to Azure Cognitive Search team. Currently we are highlighting all of the terms that are in the phrase when we try to search for exact phrase or do a proximity search.
Received an email saying that from July 15 we will be able to get updated hit highlighting mechanism.
Now it will highlight only phrases that match the full phrase query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/search/search-pagination-page-layout

So, will highlighting change only for exact phrase search? What about proximity search? Will we highlight only the phrase? Or it will work as it is working now - highlighting all terms from the phrase everywhere they occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an engineer on the Azure Search team. Users will have improved hit highlighting behavior as notified. One of the improvements is that highlighting with phrase and *proximity* queries is more accurate. So, even proximity queries will see a different behavior. The new highlights for the query `"quick brown"~2` will look like this -

`The <b>quick</b> <em>brown</em> fox jumped over the <em>quick</em> and <em>brown</em> dog but not the quick one that was not brown.`